# Running counter for JSON array using jq

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I am using `jq-1.5`. I would like to emit a running counter (ie, index) for a JSON array.

My JSON is:

```
{"Actors": "Tom,Dick,Mary"}
```

I am able to split the string into an array using `splits()`:

```
echo '{"Actors": "Tom,Dick,Mary"}' | jq --raw-output '. | ( .Actors | splits( "," ) )'
Tom
Dick
Mary
```

How do it create a running counter for each element?  I have tried using the `--arg` but cannot seem to get it to increment.

I would like to have:

```
Tom    1
Dick   2
Mary   3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_entries`. Try this:

```
echo '{"Actors": "Tom,Dick,Mary"}' | jq -r '[.Actors | splits(",")] | to_entries | map("\(.value) \(1 + .key)") | .[]' | column -t -o"   "
```

I've added `| column -t -o"  "`, i don't know how to format columns with jq.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I was looking for.  I formatted the columns by separating them with a tab.

Answer (score 2):

One can produce TSV output with `@tsv`.  With the given input,

```
jq -r '.Actors | split(",") | to_entries[] | [.value,.key] | @tsv'
```

produces:

```
Tom 0
Dick    1
Mary    2
```

If you want 1-based indexing, replace `.key` by `1 + .key` above.